# Menu in CodeIgniter with session

Tags: codeigniter, menu, session-variables

I'm creating a simple application in CI using sessions.

The nav menu is loaded in template.php file.

I want to know what is the best way to make a dinamic menu based in $this->session-userdata('logued').

If is not logued I want to show only "Log in" option in menu, but if is logued I want to load the complete menu options.

What is the best way in CI to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the solution right there:

> "If is not logued I want to show only "Log in" option in menu, but if is logued I want to load the complete menu options."

Just convert this to a PHP code and you're good to go. There's nothing special CodeIgniter can do for you in this case (I assume you can create separate menus as CI views, but that's about it)... Just check the session and show the appropriate menu based on whether the user is logged in:

View:

```
if ( $this->session->userdata('logued') ) {
    // show real menu
}
else {
    // show "log in" menu
}
```

UPDATE

If you want to do this in your controller, there are many ways as well. For example, you can load different views (if that's your structure):

Controller:

```
if ( $this->session->userdata('logued') ) {
    $menu = 'full_menu'; // or whatever the view name is
}
else {
    $menu = 'log_in_menu';
}

// your views, for example
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view($menu);
$this->load->view('content');
// etc
```

Or you can use `$data['menu'] = 'full_menu';` and then pass it to the header view (or the only/template view): `$this->load->view('header', $data);`...etc. Plenty of options to do this.

Comment: Thanks Shomz, I didn't create separate menu as views, my concern was there. So I need to create controller methods to call each menu?

Comment: No, no, just the views. You don't even have to make separate views - separate code within a view is fine, too.

Comment: See what's more readable and do it like that (if the menu is a few lines of code, for example, do it within the view, if it's really huge and complex, perhaps you could make separate views).

Answer (score 1):

Just add some information, if you want to use navigation with different access role using SESSION.
In my case, there are 2 access role. First is admin and the other is user.

The admin can manage 3 menus. And the user only can manage 2 menus. Here is my code

```
<?php if (($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['is_admin'] === true): ?>
  <ul id="sidebarnav">
    <li>
      <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-laptop-windows"></i><span class="">Main Menu</span></a>
      <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
        <li>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/dashboard" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-gauge"></i><span class="hide-menu">Dashboard</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/listpendaftaran" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-security-home"></i><span class="hide-menu">Pendaftaran</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="<?php echo base_url()?>penjadwalan" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-av-timer"></i><span class="hide-menu">Penjadwalan</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
<?php elseif (($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['is_admin'] === false): ?>
  <ul id="sidebarnav">
    <li>
      <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-laptop-windows"></i><span class="">Main Menu</span></a>
      <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
        <li>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/dashboard" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-gauge"></i><span class="hide-menu">Dashboard</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-dark" href="<?php echo base_url()?>penjadwalan" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-av-timer"></i><span class="hide-menu">Penjadwalan</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

Explanation :

When the user has logged in and has *true* value and stored into ($_SESSION['logged_in'] && the admin has the value of `1` then the menu will displayed into the admin menu (contains 3 menus).

And then, if the user has logged in and has *true* value and stored into ($_SESSION['logged_in'] && the admin has the value of `0`then the menu will displayed into the users menu (contains 2 menus).